# PHP + convert array for use with IN statement

Tags: php, sql, arrays, in-clause

Lets say I want to send an email to the people who like big sized candy.

When I do this:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT id_candy FROM `candylist` WHERE
candysize > 100") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_fetch_array( $query1 );

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT mail FROM `buyers` WHERE
candysizeinterest IN ($result)
") or die(mysql_error());
```

This query2 is of course the issue.

$result is not in a proper format to be used and then I get the obvious error of:

```
**Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'**
```

I need help to format the results of the query in a way that it looks like:

```
($val1, $val2, $val3....and so on)
```

Then I will be able to use it for an IN statement.

But I just do not know how to do so.

Comment: you should check the reference for in queries...an in query is suposed to take a comma-separated list of values, not an array

Comment: Thanks, i did. As i stated on my post that much i do know. The thing i couldt figure out by myself was converting the query result into a usable format such as you mention or as Fabio has mentioned in his helpfull answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a mistake in your sintax of `$query2` you place array instead of actual value

**change**

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT mail FROM `buyers` WHERE candysizeinterest IN ($result)
```

**to**

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT `mail` FROM `buyers` WHERE `candysizeinterest` IN ('".$result['id_candy']."')");
```

I would like to also to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for new projects.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Yet after changing it to so i get the error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING.

Comment: Thanks again! I just changed the  "'.$result[idcandy].'" because i was getting "syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING" to ".$result['id_curso']." and it worked like a charm. I appreciate it. I will also explore the implode options and see how it goes! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$array = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $query1 ))
{
   $array[] = $result['id_candy'];
}
```

Then use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$in_condition  = implode(',', $array);
```

At last

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT mail FROM `buyers` WHERE candysizeinterest IN ($in_condition)
```

**NOTE** : please switch to PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: This is exactly what my missing step was, wich i see as alternating between php and mysql querys. I will be taking note of it. Thank you.
PS: I´ll follow  the comment on PDO aswell as it is my stated intention =)

Comment: This approach is also most helpfull if you later want to print results using fwrite since the implode function will convert arrays to strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `implode()` to turn your array into a comma separated string:

`implode(',',$result);`

You can use that with IN

Answer (score 0):

To convery an array to a comma sepearted string you would use

```
implode (",",$array)
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is exactly the right php  function to use in this case and will be learning on it since your comment. I apreciatte it.